# How to get the element the mouse pointer is directly over

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a canvas where I drag and drop items. I want to put some restrictions on the drop event. For example, if item 1 have been dropped on the canvas, I want a situation where item 2 can only be drop on the canvas if the mouse pointer is directly on item 1.

I have used the Mouse.DirectlyOver but it returns null. So, How can I get element directly the mouse pointer is directly over on drop event?

Note: I am programming with C# WPF

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer takes for granted that you are using winforms.

One way you could achieve this would be to get the X/Y coordinates of the cursor to check if it is inside item1. You can use the `DragEventArgs` of the `DragDrop` event to get the mouse coordinates when the event is fired

```
private void canvas_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //Get cursor x/y coordinates
    int cursorPositionX = e.X;
    int cursorPositionY = e.Y;

    //Check if it is inside item 1
    if (cursorPositionX > item1.Location.X && cursorPositionX < item1.Location.X + item1.Width && cursorPositionY > item1.Location.Y && cursorPositionY < item1.Location.Y + item1.Height)
    {
        //The mouse is directly above item1

    }
}
```